# Maximum number of equilateral triangles in a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, tessellations

I am stuck with a question.

> Given a circle with radius $x$ cm, what is the maximum number of
>   equilateral triangles of side length 1 cm that can fit in the circle
>   without overlapping or overflowing the circle? $x$ is an integer.

How do I approach this question?

Comment: You start at http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/triincir/

Comment: I updated the visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to give an upper bound for this problem:

The total area of the triangles must not exceed the area of the circle.

\begin{align}
n \, A_t & \le A_c \iff \\
n \left( \frac{1}{2} b \, h \right) & \le \pi x^2 \iff \\
n \left(
\frac{1}{2} 
\left(
1 \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} 
\right) 
\right) 
& \le \pi x^2 \iff \\
n \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} & \le \pi x^2 \iff \\
n & \le \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{3}} x^2
\end{align}

The exact solution I do not know, e.g. see the link given by **Gerry Myerson** in the comments:
It seems the numbers $n(x)$ might be one of those many hitherto unpredictable, just given and found by trial, discrete properties.

Here is a visualization:

[image: triangles in circle]

The case $n=6$ has minimal waste of the displayed cases.